# Is it not breaking design principle of interface in c#?

Tags: c#, interface

When I googled to find the related topics about interface, I found this from MSDN website:

> For example, an interface might declare a property that has a get accessor. The class that implements the interface can declare the same property with both a get and set accessor. 
>   [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx)

Now I have a doubt. When we specifically mentioned that the property should be read only(only 'get' accessor in the interface) why is it allowed to implement 'set' accessor also?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Now I have a doubt. When we specifically mentioned that the property should be read only(only 'get' accessor in the interface) why is it allowed to implement 'set' accessor also?

There's a difference - when you use an interface, you're not "specifying that the property should be read only", but rather specifying that the contract defines a "readable property" of that specific name and type.  Basically, the interface defines the *minimum requirements* for a contract, not the absolute requirements.

If you cast the object to the specific interface, the property setter will not be available.  It's really no different than having extra properties or methods on the object that aren't available via the interface.

Comment: Exactly. Interfaces cannot be used to *Deny* access to properties, only to certify which properties are *Accessible*.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thanks Reed Copsey.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access the `set` property from a interface reference, so it doesn't matter if it's implemented or not when revealing the interface to the public.

Of course it's sometimes necessary to implement a set accessor on class side, i.e. when working with a class which allows access of classes which are in the same assembly.

Answer (score 3):

Interface is a **minimum set of requirements** that needs to be implemented but you can implement more. In this case read-write property is more than just read-only one.

Besides extending beyond requirements of a contract you can add any other methods and/or properties and also implement other interfaces in the same class.

Answer (score 2):

The code which uses the interface does not know that there is a set and so can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Think of an interface as a contract. Implementers promise to at least comply to the behaviors defined in that contract, but are not restricted to it. Interfaces allow components to interact without being tightly coupled. Therefore, an implementation may allow both `get` and `set`, but at the very least must honor the `get`.

Answer (score 0):

The class is meeting the requirements of the interface, anything else is an implementation detail of the class itself. If you're referring to the object through the interface, you're only going to see the get. So, no, it's not really breaking it, it's as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The interface though is just a declaration of how the object should be used by consumers.  It doesn't make any specifications about the implementation.  There's no inconsistency there.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IFoo {
    string Name { get; }
}

class FooImplementation : IFoo {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class FooWorker {
    public void WorkOnFoo(IFoo foo) {
        if (null == foo) throw new ArgumentNullException("foo");
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Name);
    }
}

public class Program {
    public void Main() {
        IFoo foo = new FooImplementation { Name = "Foo" };
        new FooWorker().WorkOnFoo(foo);
    }
}
```

As far as `FooWorker` is concerned, the `foo` parameter only has a `get` accessor for the `Name` property.

It's probably important to remember that that the `Name` property may still be set on `foo` via reflection or a cast.

Answer (score 0):

What Felix said is correct.

In more detail, an interface defines a *minimum* set of functionality that must exist on any object defined as implementing said interface. That provides a "common" set of functionality among all implementations of the interface, so you know that if an object implements the interface, you can call X, Y, and Z on it. Just because something is IDisposable, for instance, doesn't mean that's ALL the object can do. In fact that would make interfaces rather pointless, if they also defined a maximum amount of functionality. That's just all you care about if and when you are working with the object as an implementation of the interface; if all you need is an IDisposable, you only care about calling Dispose(), regardless of what additional members a particular IDisposable implementation may have.

Back to your example, the interface defining the property is stating that it *must* have a public get accessor. It does not, and cannot, say that it *cannot* have a public set accessor; it simply doesn't care either way. The set accessor could be public, internal, protected, private, or nonexistent; what  consumers of the interface will expect, and thus what implementors of the interface will need, is the get accessor.

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to think in terms of three types of things: an abstract `ReadableFoo` class (or `IReadableFoo` interface), along with concrete `ImmutableFoo` and `MutableFoo` classes (or `IImmutableFoo` and `IChangeableFoo` interfaces).  Someone who receives a parameter of type `ReadableFoo` will be able to read it, but will not be able to set it, and will not be able to reliably persist the data therein merely by persisting a reference.  Someone who receives a parameter of `ImmutableFoo` would be able to reliably persist the data by persisting the reference, but would not be able to change it.  Someone who receives a parameter of `MutableFoo` will be able to change the data, but not reliably persist data by persisting the reference.